# How to display emails one at a time in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to display all emails created with a loop, one at a time.

In the code below but I want to add an option to either send the emails automatically, or see them displayed and then send them manually.

While it opens the email item and displays it, when it loops it closes the previous one and opens a new one. I would like to open one and then another one as the loop goes.

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook: Set wB = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsD As Worksheet: Set wsD = wB.Worksheets("Data")
Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = wB.Worksheets("Email Format")
Dim LastRowsData As Integer
Dim LastRowEmail As Integer
Dim OA As Outlook.Application: Set OA = New Outlook.Application
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem: Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim Recipient As String

Recipient = Worksheets("Email Format").Range("A2")
LastRowsData = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastRowEmail = Worksheets("Email Format").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowsData
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(wsD.Range("H" & i).Value, _
        wsD.Range("A1:A" & LastRowsData), 0)) Then
        LastRowEmail = LastRowEmail + 1
        wsE.Range("A" & LastRowEmail).Value = wsD.Range("G" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
    
For i = 2 To LastRowEmail
    With msg
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = wsE.Range("D" & i).Value
        .To = wsE.Range("A" & i).Value
        .Subject = wsE.Range("C" & i).Value
        .Display
    End With
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Bring `Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem)` into your second `FOR` loop. Then have a msgbox at the end to ask the user if they want to send the msg. If they do, send the msg. If they dont, display a second msg where the user has to click on continue before creating a new item

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem) into your second FOR loop. Then have a msgbox at the end to ask the user if they want to send the msg. If they do, send the msg. If they dont, display a second msg where the user has to click on continue before creating a new item – Zac yesterday